# Android localization issue in country called Turkmenistan in Russian language

Tags: android

I am facing a problem in localization in Android. The Problem is that for the Russian language country called Turkmenistan the app doing localization perfectly in India.

When someone is using the app in Turkmenistan it only shows in English. Your help would be appreciated

[folder structure for value-ru](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrfrP.png)

Comment: How you declared the russian resource folder?

Comment: show your resources structure. There is something wrong with it.

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko , click  folder structure for value-ru to see folder structure and if folder structure is wrong than its should not work in India but its working correct in India ,issue is coming from Turkmenistan only

Comment: then probably there is no Locale for Turkmenistan, or Android does not know that people there speak Russian. You probably will have to manually switch locale in case of Turkmenistan

Comment: yes,May be there is no Locale for Turkmenistan,but how we can check or tell android dos't support Turkmenistan ,is there any documentation or link???

Answer (score 0):

I think `values-ru` would work. 
I assume you declared the values folder with region e.g `values-ru-rRU` and most likely that's why it doesn't work

Comment: No Alex i am using values-ru folder only

Comment: Interesting. Do you know the android version and the model. Are you sure the user using the phone in Russian? (I know I know, basic questions, but seems you should not have this problem)

Comment: Thanks,Alex may be  issue is just because of  version and model,i will check  it and will  let u know...

Comment: The only thing which can override the language and region is the network  operator (if you declared any) e.g values-mccXXX-mncXXX folder. Maybe try do decompile your release version of your apk to see what is in there for sure

Comment: sure Alex,will check